# Firebase - Is there a method for returning to root in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have this database:

```
Database:{ 
     -Blah1{
        name: "Hello SO"
     }
  }
```

And currently, I am at "name" (*by `database.child("-Blah1").child("name")`*)

So, how can I return to the root of the tree? (*In this case, "Database"*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a root reference by calling the `root` function from any child reference:

```
var rootReference = database.child("-Blah1").child("name").getRoot();
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#getRoot()

Comment: does this go to the previous parent or the main one?

Comment: @AbAppletic `.root` will always return a reference to the root of the tree, so this would return a reference to "Database" for you.

Comment: this is for web not for android. u should use databaseref...blabla..getRoot() instead

Comment: @UğurB This is correct. It's even in the tags. I will update my answer.